# i create a custom url in Codeigniter but post data can't show

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

i'm create a online shopping store with vendor system and i want every vendor profile show with his username in url.
My current url show with id number like

```
www.mydomain.com/home/profile/1
```

i want my my url show user name in url like:

```
www.mydomain.com/username
```

My Code is Here:

**Model**

```
    //get all vendors
public function vendor_profiles()
    {
        $where = array('ven_status' => 'Active');
        $this->db->select()
                 ->from('vendor_login')
                 ->where($where,'DESC');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->result_array();
    }

         //get single vendor through id number
    public function vendor_profile($id)
    {
        $where = array(
            'vendor_id' => $id,
            'ven_status' => 'Active',
        );
        $this->db->select()
                 ->from('vendor_login')
                 ->where($where,'DESC');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->first_row('array');
    }
```

**Controller**

```
//show all vendors profile
public function vendor_profiles()
    {
        $data['profiles'] = $this->front->vendor_profiles();
        $this->load->view('vendors',$data);
    }

        //show single vendor profile through id
    public function profile($id)
    {
        $data['profile'] = $this->front->vendor_profile($id);
        $this->load->view('profile',$data);
    }
```

**Views:**

```
//here is show all vendor profiles (vendors.php)

<?php foreach($profiles as $vendor) : ?>

<a href="<?=base_url();?>home/profile/<?=$vendor['vendor_id'];?>"><img src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$vendor['ven_img'];?>"></a>

<a href="<?=base_url();?>home/profile/<?=$vendor['vendor_id'];?>"><?=$vendor['ven_firstname'];?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>



           //Here is single vendor profile show (profile.php)

<p><img src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$profile['ven_logo'];?>"></p>
<p><img src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$profile['ven_img'];?>"></p>
<p>First Name : <?=$profile['ven_firstname'];?></p>
<p>Last Name : <?=$profile['ven_lastname'];?></p>
<p>Username : <?=$profile['username'];?></p>
```

**Here is My Routs:**

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB.php');
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('vendor_login');
$result = $query->result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $rout["home/profile/" . $row->username] = "home/profile/" . $row->vendor_id;
}
```

Comment: $rout or $route? Please check it first and let us know the output. 

You may consider reading CI tutorial about routing here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion:
Try to avoid creating profile URLs like

```
www.mydomain.com/username
```

It may lead to problems if someone create a username same as an existing page in your application.

E.g. Assume you have a URL like `www.mydomain.com/shop` where your shop front page is displayed. If someone creates a username *shop*, it will not work.

If your username field is unique, you needn't to create routes in this way. Instead you can use

```
$route['profile/(:any)']="home/profile/$1";
```

With this you can create a meaningful profile URL something like

```
www.mydomain.com/profile/username
```

Now in your controller Home.php change the `profile` method as follows

```
public function profile($username)
{
// call your model function to retrieve userprofile with the unique username
// the username will be on $username variable
}
```

Your profile URL can be generated as below:

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url('profile/$username');?>'><?php echo $username;?></a>
```